# Dynamic voltage and frequency scaling API

Tags: c, linux, api, cpu

Does an API (in C) exist on Linux to allow a process to dynamically change the voltage or the frequency of the core it runs on?

Answer (score 1):

There might be such a library, but even if it doesn't, you can always open the files under /sys/devices/system/cpu that configure the behavior of the CPU.
Take a look to the files under /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpufreq .

Comment: On my personal computer, the directory /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0 does not contain a cpufreq file or directory. Only some stuff related to the topology and the cache. My intent is to use dynamic voltage/frequency adaptation on a supercomputer, modifying such files is not an option as I don't have administrator access. Only a C API would solve the problem I guess...

Comment: Ok, I see. It may depend on the specific installation.

Comment: @sunmat As non-root user, you won't be able to do such things, C API or not.

Comment: @glglgl Then how can I do it programmatically in C?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the frequency voltage pair by writing to:
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu%d/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed file. There is a file for each hardware thread. However, you can only change the frequency for the entire chip (all the cores). You can find the available frequencies from:
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies

If you do not have this folder, check if your processor has Enhanced Intel SpeedStep® Technology available. If it has, go to the BIOS and enable it and you will see the folder. 
One more thing, you might need to enable/install the cpufreq module.

Hope it helps someone since the original position is old.

Answer (score 0):

CPU Dynamic Voltage-Frequency Scaling Example:

```
# See availables operation performance points
cat /sys/class/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/scaling_available_frequencies
384000 460800 600000 672000 768000 864000 960000 1248000 1344000 1478400 1555200

# See current core frequency
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/scaling_cur_freq
384000

# See current core voltage
cat /sys/class/regulator/regulator.3/microvolts
785000

# Change CPU speed to 1248000 MHz
echo 1248000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
echo 1248000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/scaling_cur_freq
1248000

cat /sys/class/regulator/regulator.3/microvolts
980000
```